# Are lambda expressions supported by Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lambda, razor

**Are lambda expressions/anonymous methods supported in the Razor view engine?**

I am having difficulty expressing the following in Razor:

```
@Model.ToList().ForEach(i =>
    {
        if (i.DealerName != null) 
        {
            <text> 
                @i.DealerName
            </text>
        }
    }
```

**Note:**  I know can solve this with `@foreach` but I need a similar solution for a 3rd party MVC control.  It using this mechanism for setting the content of the control.  It works fine for MVC .ASPX views but cannot get it to work with Razor.

MVC .ASPX equivalent (the code I would like to convert to Razor syntax):

```
<% Model.ToList().ForEach(i =>
       {
           if (i.DealerName != null)
           { 
           %> <%=i.DealerName%> <%
           };
       }); 
%>
```

This is for the Razor engine that ships with ASP.NET MVC3.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of your `<text>@i.DealerName</text>` block you could use a `Response.Write(i.DealerName);`

The result is the same, as if you drop this in a Razor page - it will execute while rendering page.. And frankly - I'm pretty sure this is what it will be compiled into anyway.

Also, since `ForEach()` returns void, you'd have to drop it in the page as a code block.
So your code would look something like this:

```
@{
    Model.ToList().ForEach(i =>
    {
        if (i.DealerName != null) 
        {
            Response.Write(i.DealerName);
        }
    });
}
```

**UPD:** If you have more serious formatting, you can resort to this nice little trick:
(unfortunately the code colouring here will not give this snippet any credit, but you'll definitely see what I mean if you drop this in visual studio. Note: this will only work in Razor pages, not code files :) )

```
@{
    Model.ToList().ForEach(i =>
    {
        if (i.DealerName != null) 
        {
            Response.Write(((Func<dynamic, object>)(
                @<text>
                    <b>Hello Dealer named: @item.DealerName
                    Multiline support is <em>Beautiful!</em>
                </text>)).Invoke(i));
        }
    });
}
```

Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: Yes `Response.Write` works but for a more complex example the string concatenation gets out of hand very quickly. :(

Comment: Yes, you're right.. I've updated the post to allow pretty much any kind of Razor code inside this function.. Enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks for your trouble you took Artiom.  I particularly like your multi line trick.  Unfortunately I cannot drop into a code block like this. As I mentioned in my question I need provide my content/template inside the component vendors lambda expression to build the control.  It seems so simple in the .ASPX code.  Am I to take it that lambda expressions is not supported in Razor the same level as for MVC .ASPX code?

Comment: Wait.. but in your .aspx example you're doing the same thing.. You're opening up a code block, and you execute a .ForEach method there..
Surely you should be able to just do the same in a Razor control.. At least I never had any issues doing that

Comment: Hmm.. Just a note, I think not everyone knows that you can put a `@{ code goes here }` block anywhere on a razor page, not just as the "head" of the .cshtml file. In fact you **have** to use code blocks like this if you want to run `void` methods in the middle of an aspx, or create new variables :)

Comment: That is the issue. It doesn't work in Razor (or at least for me).  From my findings it seems the compiler cannot work out where code/HTML starts when inside a lambda expression.

Comment: Hmm.. Could you give me an example of where the razor parser starts choking? Because the examples I provided seems to be working fine on a test page...

Comment: Line 5 in my Razor code snippet. 
The name 'text' does not exist in the current context.  
Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: Oh yes, this is due to the fact that the Razor compiler works completely differently to the aspx one... You can achieve the same effect with Razor, but you'd have to call Response.Write manually from inside the lambda expression. That's the only change you'd need to have. Just take the second snippet in my answer, and adapt it to your needs.. no? :)

Comment: @Artiom. I just tried you second snippet. Compiler error:  CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type.  It fails on the @<text> tag

Comment: Yup, sorry.. I've made a mistake there :P
Just fixed it.. Try the updated one.. it **has** to work!

Comment: Thanks it works now.  Unfortunately I have to work out if I can get into the components vendor's lambda expression. Again thanks for your trouble.

Comment: No worries. Hope you'll manage to make it work as you planned :)

Comment: +1 If I really understand, @<text>...<text> is cast as Func<T, object>?! Is razor engine doing this cast or is a c# feature? What is the name of this keyword '@<Text>'... I mean, How can I search more deeply about the internal implementation of this feature? In all cases, thank you for the explanations! :)

Comment: C# is a programming language, while Razor is more of a layout language, that gets converted into regular C# code.
Regarding the block you described, if I remember correctly it gets converted to a `Func<T, HelperResult>` although I have been casting it to the more generic `Func<T, IHtmlString>` just fine :)
More information about it would probably be anywhere where Razor is described (http://asp.net for example?), but if you want the internal workings, you'd have to dig the source of MVC and WebPages..

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can create a lambda function, and call that for each item in the body of your Razor code (the idea came from Andy in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4296206/386806)):

```
@model IEnumerable<Dealer>

@{
    Func<Dealer, object> sayHi = 
        @<text>
             <b>Hello Dealer named: @(item.DealerName)</b>
             Multiline support is <em>Beautiful!</em>
         </text>;
}

<div>
    @foreach(var dealer in Model.ToList())
    {
        sayHi(dealer);
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are supported. BUT, Razor has some weird escaping rules and extra braces will cause it to choke sometimes, including those in extended lambda expressions.

You can simplify the @Artioms answer a bit to remove those extra braces with a where and optionally a select clause

```
@{
    Model.ToList().ForEach(i =>
    {
        if (i.DealerName != null) 
        {
            Response.Write(i.DealerName);
        }
    });
}
```

becomes

```
@{
    Model.Where(i=>i.DealerName != null).ToList().ForEach(i =>
    {
            Response.Write(i.DealerName);
    });
}
```

Could also become

```
@{Model.Where(i=>i.DealerName != null).Select(i=>i.DealerName)
    .ToList().ForEach(Response.Write);}
```

Yay functional styles!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but it does not answer the question.

Comment: I reworded the top to be a bit more clear - it improves on @Artioms answer. I also provided another workaround - removing extra braces that could potentially confuse the razor compiler. I think it's useful, at the bare minimum.