# Capture the output of an Asp.Net Razor expression to a string variable in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, razor, c#-to-vb.net

I'm trying to accomplish in VB.Net 4.71 Razor syntax what [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296206/razor-how-to-render-content-into-a-variable) accomplished in C# and it's not quite working.

This is the code I have in my View:

```
@code

    Dim a As Func(Of Object, Object) = Function(item)
             @<text>
        There is text here @item
            </text>
                                       End Function

@a(0)

End code
```

The line "@a(0)" outputs "There is text here 0" to the web browser which appears to be correct.  When I try something like "Dim HtmlStr = @a(0)" inside the "code" block, I get a syntax error, Razor will not compile it.  How can I capture the output of the expression "@a(0)" to the "HtmlStr" variable?